# Python 2.7 While Loop Issue

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I am trying to write a code for a text based chat-bot as my first full scale project and I am having a weird problem with while loops that I can't figure out. My primary loop is dependent on text input, what is supposed to happen is when the user types "bye" the program ends. The only problem is when I run it, no matter what I say to it, it just prints out the same response over and over until I hit cntrl.+c or close the window. Here is the code:
    import datetime

```
print("Hi I am ChatBot V 0.0.1. I am here to converse. ")

user_name=raw_input("What is your name?")

print("Hello " + user_name + "!")

user_input=raw_input().lower().replace(" ","").replace("?","")

is_user_finished=0

while (is_user_finished == 0):

if user_input == "hi" or "hello":
    print("Hello. How are you?")

elif user_input == "whatisyourname":
    print("I do not have a name at the moment. What do you think I should be named?")
    user_input=raw_input().lower().replace(" ","").replace("?","")
    print("Good choice! I like that name!")

elif "where" and "you" in user_input:
    print("I was typed up by some kid in California")



else:
    print("I do not currently understand what you said. Sorry.")

if user_input == "bye":
    print("Good bye. It was nice talking to you!")
    is_user_finished = 1
```

Comment: Please indent the code correctly. Remember it's very important in Python.

Comment: Your code is not properly indented, and cannot run as such. Whitespace is significant in Python code. As such we can not verify your bug from this code.

Comment: As you are writing this for a learning purpose better start using Python3.x. There are lot of changes/improvements that have been done that will help you in future development.

Comment: Do not edit indentation here. Wrong indentation could be the actual cause of the problem. I rollbacked to original version.

Comment: Please double check your indentation! If it is how we see it now, you should be getting a "Expected indented block error" at your first if statement.

Comment: the indentation was correct on my code it just came out different when I put it in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that the line

```
if user_input == "hi" or "hello":
```

don't do what you think. Instead, you should do

```
if user_input == "hi" or user_input == "hello":
```

or even, in a more compact way:

```
if user_input in ["hi","hello"]:
```

Something similar happens with the line

```
elif "where" and "you" in user_input:
```

which should be

```
elif "where" in user_input and "you" in user_input:
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax issue.

the correct form should be : if A == B or A == C, instead of A == B or C, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the line

`if user_input == "hi" or "hello":`  to  `if user_input == "hi" or user_input == "hello":`

and

`"where" and "you" in user_input:`  to  `"where" in user_input and "you" in user_input:`,
because `"hello"` and `"where"` is always `True` .

Besides you should put `user_input=raw_input().lower().replace(" ","").replace("?","")` **into the while loop.**

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have proper indentation, which if the loop keeps running I assume you do, the problem, besides the things pointed out above about proper use of compound if statements is you need to add a "break" to the "bye" case.

```
if user_input == "bye":
    print("Good bye. It was nice talking to you!")
    is_user_finished = 1
    break
```